# Knockout binding is bloating html (table cells), how to create bindings with javascript or bind from parent element?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I've created a reusable grid component via knockout and I'm finding that my html is becoming very bloating with `data-bind="..."` strings particularly for `<td>` elements.

I could have a grid with 8 columns and a mere 20 rows which would yield 160 cells. The issue is all my cells look like this:

```
<td data-bind="text: typeof rowText == 'function' ? rowText($parent) : $parent[rowText],
event: { dblclick: function() { $root.rowDoubleClicked($parent); } },
css: $data.columnClass">Yale University</td>
```

I may even add future bindings.

It'd be nice if there was a way to perhaps apply a binding to `<tbody>` that would automatically apply a binding to it's child `<td>` elements. Or perhaps there is a way to apply bindings via javascript instead of using the "data-bind" attribute?

Comment: This sounds like a task for a custom binder.  I don't remember how that's done, though, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally the only one looking at the code is you (developer), so what it looks like is unimportant in the grand scheme of things. You could just format your markup to make it easier to follow:

```
<td data-bind="
    text: typeof rowText == 'function' ? rowText($parent) : $parent[rowText],
    event: { dblclick: function() { $root.rowDoubleClicked($parent); } },
    css: $data.columnClass">Yale University</td>
```

your text binding could be cleaned up by pushing back that check to the viewmodel, perhaps using a computed that does that check for you.

Knockout templates may help "pretty up" your markup, but it's really just moving it around anyways.

Comment: My biggest concern isn't looks but the time it takes the DOM to parse all the strings and the binder to break apart the same string over and over. Maybe this is micro-optimization, but I always assumed browsers could be slow and so the less everything the better. This stuff isn't getting sent over the network which is the biggest bottleneck so maybe I'm being pedantic.

Comment: I've got some HEAVY knockout markup on a few of my projects at work, and performance hasn't been an issue. subjective, I know.